# gRPC roled-base service methods

Tags: python, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm working on a gRPC server in python based on protocol buffers. I would like to differentiate the methods so that only some type of client can call certain methods.

The only possible solution that I came up is to implement the SSL/TLS bilateral authentication so the server can recognize the client from his cert, and then in each methods check if the client can or cannot call this method.
I cannot use the Token-based authentication with Google because this should work also locally without internet access.
I don't need really an authentication because I already know the clients that can use the server, I only need a mechanism to recognize them and limit the access to the methods.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: There are at least five different ways you might go about implementing some kind of restriction, but what leaps to mind from what you've shared is: when you say "I already know the clients that can use the server" it implies that the clients are under your control (or at least under the control of agents with whom you are on friendly terms), so why not just tell the clients what methods they each are and are not allowed to call? Something more complex based on security capabilities would work but may not be necessary if the clients connecting to your server aren't _adversarial_. Or are they?

Comment: After a little more reflection, I guess what I'm asking is: what's the [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model)? Against what are you trying to protect your service and your server?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The clients are other components in my software architecture. So you are right when you say that the clients are under my control. But not all the components are allowed to call all the methods. Perhaps it's not really a security problem.
The solution could to create a proto service for the different level of security. So I allow the client to use only the proto (service) that I want  its to use. What do you think?
When i wrote this question I was thinking to create something more secure than what I really need for future extensions.

Comment: It sounds like "clients invoking RPCs that they are not allowed to invoke"  would be considered a bug in the client code. And it sounds like the client code is under your control. The proper way to respond to a bug in code that you control is to _fix the bug_, not alter other code to guard against it. This seems rather straightforward; what am I missing?